# SBT 1.3.8 to update SNAPSHOT versions automatically even when in incremental compilation

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, versioning, snapshot

Since SBT 1.3.0, Coursier is the default resolver engine, therefore we removed the Coursier SBT plugin from the dependencies.

In the Coursier-plugin times, we used `COURSIER_TTL="5 min"` to control how frequently `SNAPSHOT` version should be fetched automatically, even, when `sbt ~test:compile` is used during development.

For the dependency `SNAPSHOT` project, here is the output of:

```
sbt:hub> show isSnapshot
[info] common / isSnapshot
[info]  true
[info] isSnapshot
[info]  true
```

```
sbt:hub> show packagedArtifacts
[info] Wrote C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5.0-SN
APSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\target\scala-2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

[info] common / packagedArtifacts
[info]  Map(Artifact(common, jar, jar, None, Vector(compile), None, Map(), None, false)
-> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
, Artifact(common, src, jar, Some(tests-sources), Vector(test), None, Map(), None, false
) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-t
ests-sources.jar, Artifact(common, jar, jar, Some(tests), Vector(test), None, Map(), Non
e, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5.0-SN
APSHOT-tests.jar, Artifact(common, src, jar, Some(sources), Vector(compile), None, Map()
, None, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5
.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar, Artifact(common, pom, pom, None, Vector(pom), None, Map(), None
, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\common\target\scala-2.12\common_2.12-0.5.0-SNA
PSHOT.pom)
[info] packagedArtifacts
[info]  Map(Artifact(hub, src, jar, Some(sources), Vector(compile), None, Map(), None, f
alse) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\target\scala-2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-sources
.jar, Artifact(hub, jar, jar, Some(tests), Vector(test), None, Map(), None, false) -> C:
\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\target\scala-2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar, Artifac
t(hub, jar, jar, None, Vector(compile), None, Map(), None, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Pr
ojects\hub\target\scala-2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, Artifact(hub, src, jar, Some(t
ests-sources), Vector(test), None, Map(), None, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\
target\scala-2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-tests-sources.jar, Artifact(hub, pom, pom, Non
e, Vector(pom), None, Map(), None, false) -> C:\Users\Ehnalis\Projects\hub\target\scala-
2.12\hub_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom)
```

There is a CHECKED file under `hub\common_2.12\0.5.0-SNAPSHOT` in local `.coursier` directory and that would not update while code is changing in another project that depends on `hub`, while using `~test:compile`.

`COURSIER_TTL` has not effect in 1.3.8. Is there any other way to setup SBT to frequently check for new `SNAPSHOT` versions?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting [`forceUpdatePeriod`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/4c3cd4e535a89d220a0d20f360f36212ceff9b09/sbt/src/sbt-test/dependency-management/force-update-period/test#L9) duration in `build.sbt`

```
forceUpdatePeriod := Some(5 minutes)
```

which controls

```
Duration after which to force a full update to occur
```

because according to [docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#General+troubleshooting+steps) running `update` should fix problems with SNAPSHOTs

> Run update explicitly. This will typically fix problems with out of
>   date SNAPSHOTs or locally published artifacts.

---

EDIT: Try updating to [sbt 1.3.9](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.3.9) which

> Updates to lm-coursier-shaded 2.0.0-RC6-2

where [2.0.0-RC6-2](https://github.com/coursier/sbt-coursier/releases/tag/v2.0.0-RC6-2) exposes TTL configuration

> One can now adjust the TTL, the verbosity level, the checksums, and
>   the cache policies via CoursierConfiguration, accessible via
>   csrConfiguration in sbt.

Hence try setting in `build.sbt`

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import lmcoursier.definitions.CachePolicy

csrConfiguration := csrConfiguration.value
  .withTtl(1.minute)
  .withCachePolicies(Vector(CachePolicy.LocalOnly))
```

Comment: It does not work during `~test:compile`. It should be?

Comment: @Dyin It seems on my machine with sbt 1.3.8 snapshot resolution after `publishLocal` works out-of-the-box (without doing any of the above), that is, latest snapshot is picked up by `~test`. Could you provide output of `show isSnapshot`, `show packagedArtifacts`? If you manually execute `update` does it pick up latest `publishLocal` snapshot?

Comment: Yes we have to call `update` manually to update the SNAPSHOTs. Previously, while `~test:compile` was running, after code change, when 5 minutes passed, coursier automatically checked and updated dependencies. It was kinda cool back then.

Comment: @Dyin Please provide output of `show isSnapshot`, and `show packagedArtifacts`.

Comment: On which project? The SNAPSHOT dependency? Added.

Comment: @Dyin Please see updated answer. sbt 1.3.9 updated to lm-coursier-shaded 2.0.0.RC6-2 which exposes TTL configuration.